# Is it possible that a file lock never gets released?

Tags: java, locking, release, jvm-crash

Given the following file lock request:

```java
FileLock lock = null;
try {
    lock = randomAccessFile.getChannel().lock(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, mode.shared);
    // work with file
} finally {
    if (lock != null) {
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

The targetted OS being MS Windows, is there any chance the `finally` block won't be ever executed, and thus the lock never released? For example, what if the JVM crashes? How to handle such a no-owner-lock?

Comment: There's no guarentee that the code in the finally block will ever run... You could go into an infinite loop in the code in the try { } block. As far as if/when the file lock will be released, I don't have an authoritative answer, but what I've found from experience is that even if you don't release the lock, generally it will be released shortly (not always immediately) after the JVM exits. If this doesn't do the trick, you need to restart.

Comment: @ControlAltDel By restart, you mean restarting the computer that started the (crashed) JVM?

Comment: Yes restart the computer

Comment: @ControlAltDel Exiting the JVM will release the lock if nothing else does. No need *whatsoever* to restart the computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the process exits, any OS automatically releases all resources acquired by the process, however there is no guarantee when this will happen.

In case of Windows Oracle JVM uses [LockFileEx function](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u20/jdk/file/d888ef204713/src/windows/native/sun/nio/ch/WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.c) as a native implementation and according to msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202.aspx

> If a process terminates with a portion of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the locks are unlocked by the operating system. However, the time it takes for the operating system to unlock these locks depends upon available system resources. Therefore, it is recommended that your process explicitly unlock all files it has locked when it terminates. If this is not done, access to these files may be denied if the operating system has not yet unlocked them.